# Manually Extract Theme From Forge Theme Source Code?

Tags: wordpress, themes

For instance, the yet-to-be-released Twenty Twelve theme is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/thethemefoundry/twentytwelve), but it's a [Forge](https://github.com/thethemefoundry/forge) build.

And in order to retrieve the actual theme with the normal directory structure, I'd have to install Ruby, RubyGems, Forge and some configuration to go with it.

I am no developer and I just want to use the theme. Is there a way to manually pull out the theme files [from the build](https://github.com/thethemefoundry/twentytwelve)?

This is what I am thinking:

1. All the required template, JS and CSS files are in the `build` directory.
2. [Add html5.js](https://github.com/thethemefoundry/twentytwelve/blob/master/source/assets/javascripts/html5.js) to the `javascripts` directory inside `build` directory. Then rename `javascripts` directory to `js` (<= compared its directory structure to [that on WordPress.com SVN](https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/twentytwelve/))
3. Now rename `build` directory to `twentytwelve`—the theme is ready.

Is that all, or am I missing the whole point?

***PS:** I am sure that some of you'd suggest me to download the theme directly from the [WP.com SVN repo.](https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/twentytwelve/), but the reason why I don't want to is that on GitHub I can easily track the changes to the theme.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing 'easy' about the way you're suggesting going about it.  Certainly not easier than installing SVN, pointing it to the repo, and tracking changes there (you know, when they're actually done).  It's still version controlled, still easy to see the diff, and still the latest version.  Also, note that in github, the theme files do point to `/javascripts`, so if you're renaming the directory you'll have to manually catch it in the files themselves as well.

If you really want to just get the latest, ready-to-go version of the theme, use SVN.  They push updates over when it's in a stable form, so you don't need to worry so much about whether or not there's broken functions in the version you're grabbing - or any number of weird issues when using an alpha build of the theme.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to just get the latest, ready-to-go version of the theme, use SVN. They push updates over when it's in a stable form, so you don't need to worry so much about whether or not there's broken functions in the version you're grabbing - or any number of weird issues when using an alpha build of the theme.

Answer (score 2):

While that will *kind* of work, you should really either:

1. Use the GitHub repository the way it was meant to (clone it, and use Forge to build the theme).
2. Wait for the theme to actually be released.

While you might be able to extract the theme as-is from the `/build` directory, there's no real way for you "track the changes to the theme" since the changes will be made in the `/source` directory.  There's no guarantee the committers will build the theme before pushing (which is how the `/build` directory is currently kept in sync.

---

## Update

If you've been following active development, Twenty Twelve was just rolled into WordPress trunk for the upcoming (late 2012) release of version 3.5:

> ### Changeset [21261](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21261)
>
> **Timestamp:** 07/12/12 04:20:46 (14 hours ago)
>   **Author:** nacin
>   **Message:** The Twenty Twelve for WordPress.
>
> props drewstrojny, lancewillett.
>
> also props corvannoorloos, jeffsebring, kobenland, iandstewart, mfields,
>   mtdesign, op12no2, philiparthurmoore, sixhours, mamaduka.

So rather than playing around with extracting the theme via GitHub, just use Subversion to check out WordPress trunk and look at the `/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve` directory.